# Can i include the "vcredist_x86.exe" in my setup

Tags: visual-c++, installation, installshield, redistributable

I have an application developed using c++\cli on vs2008. As you are aware to deploy this application on any machine, i need the vc++ redistributable to be installed on the target machine.

I wanted to know if i could include the vcredist_x86.exe in my setup (created using InstallShield) and install it as a pre-build event?

Comment: I seem to recall that InstallShield list this redist among its predefined prerequisites. If it's true, then it's as simple as checking the appropriate checkbox

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know if it is allowed: Yes. This is why it is called redistributable.

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) describes exactly what you want to do.

Comment: That means i dont need to take any special permission from Microsoft to include it in my setup?

Comment: @rumDeep: No special permssion needed. Have a look at the link I added to the answer.